# WebSphereMQ certificate label setting doesn't work for XMS but does work for amqpmdnet

Tags: c#, .net, ibm-mq

This code with amqmdnet.dll (version 8.0.0.5) works just fine (Server set SSLCAUTH to Required so certificate label setting is a must):

```
    public MQQueueManager GetWmqQueueManager(MqConfig config)
    {
        var props = new Hashtable
        {
            {MQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY       , config.HostName},
            {MQC.PORT_PROPERTY            , config.Port},
            {MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY         , config.ChannelName},
            {MQC.SSL_CIPHER_SPEC_PROPERTY , config.SslCipherSpec},
            {MQC.SSL_PEER_NAME_PROPERTY   , config.SslPeerName},
            {MQC.SSL_CERT_STORE_PROPERTY  , config.SslPath},
            {MQC.SSL_CIPHER_SUITE_PROPERTY, config.SslCipherSuit}
        };

        MQEnvironment.CertificateLabel = config.CertLable;

        var queueManager = new MQQueueManager(config.QueueManagerName, props);
        return queueManager;
    }
```

Not I want to use IBM.XML.dll (version 8.0.0.5) and this code throws "MQRC_SSL_INITIALIZATION_ERROR" exception with error code AMQ9642 (found in error logs):

```
    protected static IConnection GetXmsConnection(MqConfig config)
    {
        var factoryFactory = XMSFactoryFactory.GetInstance(XMSC.CT_WMQ);

        var cf = factoryFactory.CreateConnectionFactory();

        cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_HOST_NAME            , config.HostName);
        cf.SetIntProperty   (XMSC.WMQ_PORT                 , config.Port);
        cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_CHANNEL              , config.ChannelName);
        cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_SSL_CIPHER_SPEC      , config.SslCipherSpec);
        cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_SSL_PEER_NAME        , config.SslPeerName);
        cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_SSL_KEY_REPOSITORY   , config.SslPath);
        cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_SSL_CIPHER_SUITE     , config.SslCipherSuit);

        cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_SSL_CLIENT_CERT_LABEL, config.CertLable);

        cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER        , config.QueueManagerName);
        cf.SetIntProperty   (XMSC.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE      , XMSC.WMQ_CM_CLIENT_UNMANAGED);

        var con = cf.CreateConnection(); // <-- exception

        return con;
    }
```

AMQ9642 says:

> SSLCAUTH(REQUIRED) has been specified on the server side (RCVR)
>   channel definition requiring that the client (SDR) supplies a valid
>   certificate.

StackTrace:

```
IBM.XMS.Client.WMQ.Factories.WmqConnectionFactory.CreateProviderConnection(XmsPropertyContext connectionProps)
       in IBM.XMS.Client.Impl.XmsConnectionFactoryImpl.CreateConnection(String userID, String password)
       in IBM.XMS.Client.Impl.XmsConnectionFactoryImpl.CreateConnection()
```

Exception details:

```
ErrorCode: CWSMQ0006
CompCode : 2
Reason   : 2393
```

Question is what is wrong with second piece of code?
Am I missing something?

EDIT1:
I'm using WebSphereMQ 8.0.0.5 and XMS is also 8.0.0.5

Comment: What version of MQ and XMS are you using please?

Comment: @Shashi 8.0.0.5 both

Comment: I think it's worth opening a PMR with IBM.

Comment: @Shashi only IBM customers could open PMR. I am not an IBM paid customer because I'm only consuming IBM WebSphere queue.

Comment: OK. I will quickly try and see if I can recreate your issue and advice

Comment: Tried XMS .NET sample code similar to yours. I am not seeing any issue, works fine. When running XMS application, does the certificate label you are using matches that of the user logged in?

Comment: @Shashi certificate label is in format "ibmwebspheremq{somename}" where {somename} doesnt match my user name. It works fine with amqpmdnet and I dont set any setting about {somename} in amqpmdnet. Does XMS require my windows user name to be there? like this - "ibmwebspheremqusername"? Or some other username?

Answer (score 1):

This is the snippet I used. Note I passing user id and password to createConnection call because I have user authentication enabled. Without them, I would get MQRC 2035 error.

```
            fact = XMSFactoryFactory.GetInstance(XMSC.CT_WMQ);
            conf = fact.CreateConnectionFactory();

            conf.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, XMSC.WMQ_CM_CLIENT_UNMANAGED);
            conf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER, "QM1");
            conf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_HOST_NAME, "localhost");
            conf.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_PORT, 1414);
            conf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_CHANNEL, "NET.SVRCONN");
            conf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_SSL_KEY_REPOSITORY, "C:\\ProgramData\\IBM\\MQ\\qmgrs\\QM1\\ssl\\CLIENT");
            conf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_SSL_CIPHER_SPEC, "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA");
            conf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_SSL_PEER_NAME, "CN=QM1,OU=QMHOST,OU=LAB,OU=PAS,O=COM,L=BLR,ST=KA,C=IN");
            conf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_SSL_CLIENT_CERT_LABEL, "ibmwebspheremqsamantha");

            mqConn = conf.CreateConnection("samantha","Passw0ord");
```

Comment: My queue provider doesn't have user authentication enabled so I don't have any username/password, only certificate.

Comment: And also when I use CreateConnection(string,string) exception thrown: Unhandled exception at 0x000000007716F3E2 (ntdll.dll) Heap has been corrupted (parameters: 0x00000000771E8430). StackTrace: MyApp -> vshost-clr2.exe -> IBM.XMS.dll -> ntdll.dll -> kernel32.dll

Comment: @Szer - I believe you will need to reach out to IBM support team somehow, probably through the team that owns MQ license.

Comment: There the fixes [IT24119](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IT24119) and [IJ04255](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IJ04255) related to your problem.